# firebase functions push Notifications to specific user

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

i want to send Push notification via firebase functions to the user who posted the post when some other user likes his/her post.

[i want to get the highlighted user-id in the image to get fcm token of this user id stored in other tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhRZK.jpg)

here is my firebase function code below.

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');


    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/user-posts/{userID}/{pushId}/stars/')
        .onWrite(event=> {
            var request = event.data.val();

            console.log("request",request);
            console.log("key",Object.keys(request)[0]);
            var key = Object.keys(request)[0];
            var token;




            const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: 'You have a new follower!',
            body: 'is now following you.'
          }
        };



             const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
             .ref(`/users-notifications/${key}`)
             .once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
                    console.log("val",snapshot.val());
                        token= snapshot.val();


                        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,payload)
            .then(response=>{
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);

            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log("error sending message",error);
            })
        })

                    }, function(error) {
                        // The Promise was rejected.
                    console.error(error);
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can backwards traverse the DB tree by using the event ref's parent property.

```
userID = event.data.ref.parent.parent.parent.key
```

parent of event.data.ref is "stars"
parent of "stars" is your pushID
parent of pushID is userID

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting it from the uri with `event.params.userID`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17942984)

Comment: This is the proposed solution by me. I mistakenly made it a question.